# what is the value of the integral

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

I need to know how to find the value of the integral?

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{(r-z)(rz-1)}, 0<r<1$$

Do I need to find the residue at $z=r,1/r$? as they are simple poles? in any case please tell me what is the final answer. Thank you

Comment: *in any case please tell me what is the final answer*... In any case, no. *Do I need to find the residue at z=r,1/r?* Yes you do, but only at the pole $z=r$ since the path $|z|=1$ does not enclose the pole $z=1/r$.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather be shown the way to do this kind of problem, and then find the final answer yourself, than just be told the answer?

Comment: @eric You seem to be new here, so I'll try to explain the rules around here. It's OK to ask for help with your homework here, but it's *not* OK to ask people to do your homework for you. Stating explicitly that you're more interested in the final answer than in how to solve the problem is thus a good way to get your question downvoted, and hopefully left unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

Hints without final answers:

**Way 1 - Cauchy's Integral Theorem:**

$$\frac1{2\pi i}\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac1{(r-z)(rz-1)}dz=\frac1{2\pi i}\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{\frac1{rz-1}}{r-z}dz$$

And now remember that under some well known conditions, we have that

$$\frac1{2\pi i}\int\limits_C\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz=f(z_0)$$

**Way 2 - Residue Theorem:**

$$\lim_{z\to r}\;\left[(z-r)\frac1{(z-r)(rz-1)}\right]=\ldots$$